# Identify Each IEnumerator Uniquely

Tags: unity-game-engine

My player character spawning multiple colors waves and try to detect upcoming objects.
Here is the small snapshot of the overall idea:

[image]

I have spawned pink and blue color waves for testing purposes. I have used IEnumerator (Thread) to generate each color wave.
Now two enumerators/threads working separately and completed their job properly. I don't have a problem with their work.

now I require some identifier or index to uniquely identify each running thread and how to manage this with c# that I don't know!

Comment: This is a bit of a nitpick but you really shouldn't think of IEnumerators as threads, they are not a separate thread, they're all on the same thread. they just are neat ways to pause and resume execution of a function

Comment: But there are behaving without interfering with each other - if I two times call IEnumerator one after another then both tasks get complete successfully from A to Z - I require to call the IEnumerator multiple time so I want to identify each execution id.

Comment: Every time you start a coroutine it constructs a new `IEnumerator` object, and each one runs independently but they will run one execution per frame (even if that execution is just waiting) and they will do this sequentially all on the same thread. You can read about how it works [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) if you like

Comment: Yes, I am getting you properly into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a list of `IEnumerator` objects, like

```
List<IEnumerator> coroutines = new List<IEnumerator>();
```

then add each coroutine to your list

```
void Start()
{
    coroutines.Add(CoroutineOne());
    coroutines.Add(CoroutineTwo());
    foreach (var c in coroutines)
    {
        StartCoroutine(c);
    }
}
```

If you add a `yield return null` to the final line of your coroutines you can then check if they have reached this state with  `IEnumerator.Current`

```
IEnumerator CoroutineOne()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("one" + i);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

and then where you're managing them

```
 void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < coroutines.Count; i++)
    {
        if(coroutines[i].Current == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Corutine " + i +" has finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

You can then use this to manage your active coroutines

```
coroutines.RemoveAll(x => x.Current == null);
```

This will keep only active ones in your list and you can use `coroutine.Count` to get how many are active at once / get valid indexes for your array

Comment: Thank you for showing me one way to deal with this situation - one question based on your IEnumerator.Current concept - do you explained this to detect the end of coroutine?

Comment: Well you asked how to manage each running coroutine,  this will let you see if one is still running or has ended

Comment: Thank you - now let me implement your suggestion within my project and give you feedback about the success :)

Comment: Still, within the IEnumerator execution, how can I detect what is my index within the list? - My IEnumerator list will not be fixed as you mentioned at the above example but it will depend on the player how many waves he will generate.

Comment: @Siddharth i've edited my answer to better answer your question

Comment: I have already done this - Coroutines removed from the list which are already expired. I want to detect within the coroutine that, what is my index within the list!! This index will become useful for me to manage other parameters.

Comment: @Siddharth I see, i understand your question not. I've once again altered my answer to hopefully help. Now using a `Dictionary` you can have a unique ID and use a `foreach` loop to get all the `KeyValuePairs` in it

Comment: Please revert back your answer to List collection rather than Dictionary and keep the key that you passed as an argument within coroutine because I have passed List's count value to get actual id of the coroutine - then after this is a perfect solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Siddharth okay answer was reverted

Comment: Still, you require to pass List count in each method call of the Coroutine to make this correct.